# Azure Devops scheduled pipeline does not trigger

Tags: azure-devops, cron, azure-pipelines, scheduled-tasks, jobs

I have the following configuration: **Azure DevOps Server Version Dev18.M170.8**

```
trigger: none # No CI build
pr: none # Not for pull requests

schedules:
- cron: "* * * * *"
  displayName: Every minute build
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  always: true
  
jobs:
- job: RunMyCustomTask
  pool: 'DedicatedPoolWith1Agent'
  condition: always()
  steps:
  - task: mycustomtask@0'
```

The pipeline is created for a separate repo and has a dedicated agent pool. It should run, normally, every minute, based on the configuration. This is critical for me. I can change to every 2 minutes or 5 minutes, but it does not matter, it must be scheduled precisely at the right intervals.

Now, I have the issue that the pipeline is scheduled every minute, and then, for no whatsoever reason, it is not scheduled anymore. I have checked this during a day, and it happened that it wasn't scheduled for 6 minutes the most.
I do not understand why this is happening. Any ideas or suggestions? I need schedules to be guaranteed. Trigger and pr: none makes no difference, with or without them.
Image example:
[image: scheduled pipeline not executing 6 minutes]

[image: Agent execution logs]

Comment: Is there a chance that you don't have enough agents? Can you go to agent details and check `Wait time`?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej as I mentioned in the question, I have a dedicated pool and a dedicated single agent just for this pipeline. No other pipelines use this agent or pool. In theory, the Agent should get a new scheduled pipeline run every minute and executed it, with a duration of maximum 1 minute, and normally under 1 minute start to end. Anyway, this does not explain why Azure DevOps Server does not schedule the pipeline for 6 minutes. If there were agent issues, I would have had piling scheduled runs, not gaps.

Comment: What do you see when you click on [scheduled runs button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scheduled-runs-view)?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej I added a screenshot for the Agent Jobs, with highlight of the moment with issue.

Comment: Is it the same when you use MS Hosted agents? Is ti possible for you to check?

Comment: Regarding the scheduled runs button, it shows next 10 schedules correctly. But they are not executed when they are scheduled (Sometimes obviously). Regarding MS Hosted, yes, I will do that. The problem is that I cannot use MS Hosted Agents always, because of OnPremises software.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that Azure DevOps pipelines is the appropriate place to be running frequent, short-lived processes on a short timer.

The documentation even states that there is a limit of about 1000 jobs per week: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#limits-on-the-number-of-scheduled-runs

> There are certain limits on how often you can schedule a pipeline to run. These limits have been put in place to prevent misuse of Azure Pipelines resources - particularly the Microsoft-hosted agents. This limit is around 1000 runs per pipeline per week.

Based on your statement, *it must be scheduled precisely at the right intervals*, I'd reconsider whether pipelines are the right tool for this job. There is no real-time guarantee with scheduled pipelines.

Comment: I understand about Microsoft Hosted, but I'm running in an On-Premises Environment with my own resources. How your answer relates to my problem?

Comment: Additionally, I stated clearly that I can change the frequency, but I need the times/intervals to be guaranteed. I don't necessarily need 1 minute cron scheduled pipeline runs.

Comment: @XMight The limit is regardless of hosted or private agent. And like I said, **there is no real-time guarantee**. It will do its best to run the pipeline at the scheduled time, but it may not run immediately at that time for a variety of reasons (service unavailability, agent unavailability, etc).

Comment: It makes sense what @DanielMann is saying. You can create maybe another question and if you provide more details what actually do you need to run on scheduled manner maybe we will find a proper approach for you.